# Induction Proof (relating two recurrences)

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction

Let $L(n) = n + 2 L\left(\frac{n}{2}\right), \, L(1) = 1,$

and $U(n) = 9n + 2U\left(\frac{n}{2}\right), \, U(1) = 9.$

Prove by induction that $U(n) = 9L(n)$ where $n = 2^k$.

I attempted to prove this question but I did not get the correct end result to prove it.

Can someone please help me with this induction proof? Help would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't remove content from a question just because it was solved. SE is a QA site; people want to come back later to see if their question was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $U(n)=9L(n)$, you already have the base case established. This also means it holds for all $k<n$, namely $\frac{n+1}{2}<n$. Then,

$U(n+1) = 9(n+1) + 2U(\frac{n+1}{2}) = 9n + 9 + 9*2L(\frac{n+1}{2})$.

But,

$L(n+1) = (n+1) + 2L(\frac{n+1}{2}) $

$\Rightarrow 2L(\frac{n+1}{2}) = L(n+1)-n-1$.

Then, since $\frac{n+1}{2}<n$, we have

$U(n+1) = 9n + 9 + 9(L(n+1)-n-1) = 9L(n+1)$,

as desired.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response Jeremy.
I noticed at the end it should have been 9L(n+1) instead of just L(n+1). How come it is just L(n+1)? Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: Looks like a typo.

Comment: Yes this was a typo, sorry it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional observation that may be helpful one sees that if
$$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} d_k 2^k$$
is the binary representation of $n$ then the two recurrences can be solved **exactly** for all $n$ (not just powers of two) by putting $L(0)=0$ and $U(0)=0$ and otherwise
$$L(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} \sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} d_j 2^{j-k}
\quad\text{and}\quad
U(n) = 9\times
 \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} \sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} d_j 2^{j-k}.$$
This is immediate from the two recurrences. At that point there is nothing left to prove.